# Client tool to query remote FAST ESP 5.3 server accessible over http

Tags: fast-esp

Is there a client tool available to execute FAST queries on a remote FAST ESP 5.3 server that is accessible over http?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the server is accessible over http, you can probably go directly to the qr (query/results) server on port 15100 of the admin node & send queries to it directly via wget.  The entire query api can be used via http, results will come back in xml or plaintext depending on which search template you select (/cgi-bin/xsearch or /cgi-bin/search on generic deployments).

Details on the full query language and url params can be found here:
[Fast 5.3 Query Language Parameters Guide](http://nesfast1.scot.nhs.uk:16089/help/pdfs/assets/pdf/ESP_Query_Language_Parameters_Guide.pdf) (doc hosted on a non-Fast/MS site ... couldn't find it on msdn, but its what you want).

good luck.